# Subquery inside inner join on where condition, showing token in error 'select'

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-ce

```
SELECT ma.openingbalance, 
       ma.closingbalance, 
       ct.currentopeningbalance AS AmtBeforeTransaction, 
       ct.currentclosingbalance AS AmtAfterTransaction, 
       ct.transactionnumber, 
       ct.transactionid, 
       ct.ammount 
FROM   masteraccount AS ma 
       INNER JOIN companytransactions AS ct 
               ON ma.companyid = ct.companyid 
WHERE  ( ct.transactionid = (SELECT Max(ct.transactionid) AS max 
                             FROM   companyfinancials 
                             WHERE  ( ma.financialid = 1 ) 
                                AND ( ma.companyid = 1 )) ) 
       AND ( ct.companyid = 1 ) 
       AND ( ct.financialid = 1 )
```

The join query and the subquery is running fine separately. But when I put them together different errors show up at different times, all of them are like 'token in error' select in different lines and offsets. Please help me out

Comment: Can you put this up in Sql fiddle?

Comment: How could your subquery be fine when run separately is unexplicable. The `MAX(ct.transactionid) as max` is trying to reference a table that doesn't exist in the subquery

Comment: couldn't the entire WHERE be part of the JOIN criteria in the first place?

Comment: At first I tried to put the subquery separately but it didn't work. Then I used this structure. I am totally in darkness how to design the query Steve

Comment: I want to select one row only where the companyId and financialId will be the identity of the records and the subquery will fetch the max transaction for the specified company

Comment: Thank you D Stanley for the answer. When I put the subquery without any references in the query builder, it automatically converts to one having the references. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

You've referenced outside aliases in your inner select.  Change

```
(SELECT Max(ct.transactionid) AS max 
     FROM   companyfinancials 
     WHERE  ( ma.financialid = 1 ) 
        AND ( ma.companyid = 1 ))
```

TO

```
(SELECT Max(transactionid) AS max 
     FROM   companyfinancials 
     WHERE  ( financialid = 1 ) 
        AND ( companyid = 1 ))
```